# Sorting functions in an asymptotically, non-decreasing order of growth

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, computer-science

I'm trying to sort these functions asymptotically non-decreasing order of growth using big-oh and big-theta notation such that $g1 = O(g2), g2 = O(g3), g3 = Q(g4), g4 = O(g5), \dots$

$\left(\sqrt{16}\right)^{\log _2\left(n\right)},\:2^{\left(\sqrt{n}\right)},\:200n\log _2\left(n\right),\:n^2,\:\left(n\cdot 2^{n/4}\right),\:\left(2/n\right)\cdot \:n!,\:16^{\log _2\left(n\right)},\:\log _2\left(n^{150000}\right),\:\left(\log _2\left(n\right)\right)^2,\:2^{100000},\:2^{3^n}$

I am supposed to justify using limits, I'm unsure of how to approach this and what a proper answer would look like. A push in the right direction and or an example would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Start comparing one by one, you can use some kind of sorting algorithm to avoid doing all ${11 \choose 2 }= 55$ comparison, maybe like quick sort.